# Set total pageable records in DetailsView ClientTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid, telerik-mvc

mvc3, telerik mvc 2011.2.712

I have a grid with a DetailView.  In the DetailView, I have another grid in the ClientTemplate of the DetailView.  In the nested grid, I need to set the total number of records for paging.  The number of records is one of the columns in the master grid, so I am able to access it via this syntax, `"<#= NumPackages #>"`.  The problem is that `paging.Total` takes a single parameter of type int.  I tried the following:

```
paging.Total(int.Parse("<#= NumPackages #>"))
```

but of course that didn't work because at the time Parse executes, the expression `"<#= NumPackages #>"` hasn't evaluated yet.  At this point the only option I see is to simply bring back all the records and let the grid figure out the total.  The max records would only be 99, so it is workable.  I wouldn't even be worrying about it, but the query that gets the data is a very complex and thus takes a few seconds to get through.  Any one know how to get the `NumRecords` from the master grid and supply it to the paging.Total of the child grid?

Here's my grid definition:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<DtsWeb.Models.District.DistrictSearchResultItem>()
.Name("OriginationGrid")
.DataBinding(db => db.Ajax()
    .Select("DistrictOriginationSelect", "District")
)
.DataKeys(key => key.Add(e => e.ID))
.Columns(col => { 
    col.Bound(c => c.CreationDate);
    col.Bound(c => c.CreatedBy);
    col.Bound(c => c.ShipTo);
    col.Bound(c => c.NumPackages);
    col.Bound(c => c.LabelComment);
    col.Bound(c => c.UserComment);
    col.Bound(c => c.ID).ClientTemplate("<button id='<#= ID #>' onclick='editOrigination(<#= ID #>)'>Edit</button>").Title("");
})
.DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
    Html.Telerik().Grid<DtsWeb.Models.District.PackageDeliveryItem>()
    .Name("Package_<#= ID #>")
    .DataBinding(dbp => dbp.Ajax()
        .Select("OriginationPackages", "District", new { originationID = "<#= ID #>" })
    )
    .Pageable(paging => paging.Total(int.Parse("<#= NumPackages #>")).PageSize(10))
    .ToHtmlString()
))
.Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(25))
.Sortable(sort => sort.OrderBy(c => c.Add(e => e.CreationDate)))
.Render();
%>
```

In the process of proof reading my question, it occurred to me that I might find a solution through the use of client events.  I will post this question as is and update it if I find a solution.

Comment: Ok, I was going about this wrong.  I needed to enable custom binding and then set the total in the controller method.  I will post the full solution once enough time has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was going about this wrong.  I needed to enable custom binding and then set the total in the controller method.  Here's the modified grid definition (notice the code to enable custom binding as well as the additional parameter to Ajax().Select, both in the nested grid):

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<DtsWeb.Models.District.DistrictSearchResultItem>()
.Name("OriginationGrid")
.DataBinding(db => db.Ajax()
    .Select("DistrictOriginationSelect", "District")
    //.Update("DistrictOriginationUpdate", "District")
)
.DataKeys(key => key.Add(e => e.ID))
.Columns(col => { 
    col.Bound(c => c.CreationDate);
    col.Bound(c => c.CreatedBy);
    col.Bound(c => c.ShipTo);
    col.Bound(c => c.NumPackages);
    col.Bound(c => c.LabelComment);
    col.Bound(c => c.UserComment);
    col.Bound(c => c.ID).ClientTemplate("<button id='<#= ID #>' onclick='editOrigination(<#= ID #>)'>Edit</button>").Title("");
    //col.Command(com => com.Edit());
})
.DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
    Html.Telerik().Grid<DtsWeb.Models.District.PackageDeliveryItem>()
    .Name("Package_<#= ID #>")
    .DataBinding(dbp => dbp.Ajax()
        .Select("OriginationPackages", "District", new { originationID = "<#= ID #>", total = "<#= NumPackages #>" })
    )
    .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
    .EnableCustomBinding(true)
    .ToHtmlString()
))
.Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(25))
.Sortable(sort => sort.OrderBy(c => c.Add(e => e.CreationDate)))
.Render();
%>
```

Here's my controller code for anyone whose interested:

```
    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult OriginationPackages(GridCommand command, int originationId, int total)
    {
        this.entities = new DtsEntities();

        var list = DistrictSearchResultItem.GetPackages(this.entities, originationId, command.Page, command.PageSize, total);

        return View(new GridModel { Data = list, Total = total });
    }
```

I hope this can help someone else.